# Anonymous users email subscriptions to node updates

Tags: rules, emails, notifications

How can I achieve the following:

I want to be able to notify the anonymous user by email when I update a node.

Example: I have `mysite.com/cool-page. I want to have a block with an email field so users can subscribe basically to that page. And every time I update the content from that page, I want the subscribed users to be notified by email.

With [Rules](https://drupal.org/project/rules) I managed to set something up so every time my node is updated it will send an email to users of a role. The problem is that I want to send an email to a list from the database (that I previously collected in a subscription block).

I use Drupal 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the [MailChimp Subscriptions module](https://drupal.org/project/mailchimp_subscriptions). It won't let you subscribe to individual pages, but instead to node authors. (Never tested that)

Another way, might be to use the [Simple Subscriptions module](https://drupal.org/project/simple_subscription) and to write some custom code to achieve exactly what you want.

Comment: By the same manner I can easily use SimpleNews module which is integrated with rules. All I have to do is create a newsletter which will be basically a page with a message, and specify rule criteria to send the email.

Comment: Correct, though simplenews won't allow you to use other node types except for those defined as newsletter. I thought of that too, but had the impression that this meets your use case even less.

Comment: But it's more useful because I only have to send a notification something like 'Page has been updated... check it out! etc..' and condition the rule to send newsletter on node update. Anyway, will keep searching to find a more elegant solution! Thank you!